# Replace A Pattern In String Using Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace test word up to next comma in a string.
For example the string is "`abc test xy, tmy test 1, vks , csb`";
The output after replacement should be "`abc , tmy, vks,csb`".
Removed test followed by any character or number up to comma.

I tried the following code but did not work.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class TESTREPLACE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abc test   xy, tcs test  1, vks , csb ";

        String regex = " default.+\\,";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("\\,"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting your post to improve its display quality? You seem to be a long time member of this site and probably know what a good quality post should look like.

Comment: Use `.replaceAll("\\btest[^,]*", "")`. However, if you replace `+` with `+?`, it would also work.

Comment: If a string contains "test" followed by nothing but a comma (so "test,") should "test" be removed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are not very clear in your example, do you also need to remove spaces after commas?
Anyway this regex is matching the word `test` followed by any character except for the comma `,`: `(test[^,]+)` using it in your `replaceAll` should do the trick.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final String input = "abc test xy, tmy test 1, vks , csb";
    final String expected = "abc , tmy , vks , csb";
    final String got = replaceTestWordUpToComma(input);
    assertEquals(expected, got);
}

private String replaceTestWordUpToComma(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("test[^,]+", "");
}
```